# jquery - how to addClass based on the content of an element?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, addclass

Suppose you have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Group 1</td>
<td>some data here</td>
<td>Group 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and you want it to be like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="group1">Group 1</td>
<td>some data here</td>
<td class="group2">Group 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Both Nick Craver's and Kevin's solutions here below work nicely. Thanks guys! Why would I wnted to do such thing? To style a timetable for a non-profit organization that provides workshops.

Comment: Why would you like to do such a thing? It stinks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure *why* you'd do this (I'd stop and look at that honestly, there's probbly a better way).

You *can* make it generic though.  For example you could pass a function to [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), for example:

```
$("td:contains('Group ')").addClass(function() { 
  return this.innerHTML.replace("Group ", "group");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your content will only contain 'Group X' you could just remove the spaces and convert the text to lower.

For example:

```
$('td').each(function() {
     var className = $(this).html().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
     $(this).addClass(className);
});
```